# Gulp Plumber Returning Errors in Sass

Tags: sass, gulp

My terminal still returns an error and breaks my task when there's an error in my Sass. This is what my task looks like:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./src/scss/*.scss', './src/scss/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths : [
        './lib/basscss/scss',
        './lib/fluidbox/css'
      ],
      outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(prefix({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/css'))
    .pipe(gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/css'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});
```

Any idea why it keeps breaking? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can include an error handler in plumber. This will save you from unexpected breaks.

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./src/scss/*.scss', './src/scss/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        this.emit('end');
      }
    }))
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: [
        './lib/basscss/scss',
        './lib/fluidbox/css'
      ],
      outputStyle: 'expanded'
    }))
    .pipe(prefix({
      browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
      cascade: false
    }))
    .pipe(minifyCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/css'))
    .pipe(gzip())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./_site/public/css'))
    .pipe(reload({
      stream: true
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this question three years ago but now I've faced the same issue. My solution was to remove `return` from function - and it finally start working.